# Add a value to member list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a some shopping web with mvc, which have a `IdProduct` `Name` `Price` And `Quantity`. So i just create a model to the product which the product have `IdProduct` `Name` `Price`, the Quantity will be add when i input in the web. In the Controller i just create a list to set the value of a model. But when i add the value of Quantity, the value just made a new list. 
How can i add the value of quantity to one of the member of the list ?

````
Barang listBarang = new Barang();
if (TempData.Peek("daftarBarang") == null)
{
    List<Barang> dftrBarang = new List<Barang>
    {
        new Barang{IdBarang = 1, NamaBarang = "Mouse", HargaBarang = 50000},
        new Barang{IdBarang = 2, NamaBarang = "Keyboard", HargaBarang = 100000},
        new Barang{IdBarang = 3, NamaBarang = "Monitor", HargaBarang = 2500000},
    };
    TempData.Add("daftarBarang", dftrBarang);
}
List<Barang> daftarBarang = (List<Barang>)TempData.Peek("daftarBarang");
return View(daftarBarang);```
````

The ouput is:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Id Barang | Nama Barang |    Harga Barang |  Quantity |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
|         1 | Mouse       |           50000 |         0 |
|         2 | Keyboard    |          100000 |         0 |
|         3 | Monitor     |         2500000 |         0 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

when I submit Quantity, that's make a new list. And that's wrong

[EDIT] VIEW

```
<form action="~/tambah" method="post">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td> Id Barang</td>
                    <td> Nama Barang</td>
                    <td> Harga Barang</td>
                    <td> Quantity</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        {
                        <td>@item.IdBarang</td>
                        <td>@item.NamaBarang</td>
                        <td>@item.HargaBarang</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="Quantity" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: As I know, you want to show a list of the product and you can edit the quantity value, right?

Comment: yap, but i want the quantity just add into the member of the list

Comment: Could you post your code in View?

Comment: ok i just edit the post. You can see now

Comment: I have a question. Why don't you add Quantity property into Barang class?

Comment: for dynamic value. Not static

Comment: Yeah. The value of Quantity is dynamic. Maybe I should add a sample. It's more clearly.

Comment: ok i waiting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, my friend.

Here is a sample. Hope to help :))

---

//I added a Quantity property

```
public class BarangsViewModel
    {
        public int IdBarang { get; set; }
        public string NamaBarang { get; set; }
        public double HargaBarang { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

//Controller

```
public ActionResult Products()
        {
            var products = new List<BarangsViewModel>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var obj = new BarangsViewModel
                {
                    IdBarang = i,
                    NamaBarang = $"This is job {i}",
                    HargaBarang = i                    
                };
                products.Add(obj);
            }

            return View("Products", products);
        }



           [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Products(List<BarangsViewModel> model)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

//Views

```
@model List<WebApp.Models.BarangsViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Products";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table id="mygrid" class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> Id Barang</td>
                <td> Nama Barang</td>
                <td> Harga Barang</td>
                <td> Quantity</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="rodetailrowdata">
            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Model[i].IdBarang
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].IdBarang)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Model[i].NamaBarang
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].NamaBarang)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Model[i].HargaBarang
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].HargaBarang)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].Quantity, new {@type ="number" })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```